# persistentvolumeclaim "esdata1" not found or pod has unbound PersistentVolumeClaims

Tags: docker, kubernetes

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
      container_name: elasticsearch
      environment:
        - cluster.name=elstic-cluster
        - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
        - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      ulimits:
        memlock:
          soft: -1
          hard: -1
      volumes:
        - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      ports:
        - 9200:9200
      networks:
        - hcnet
```

I am getting the error : "persistentvolumeclaim "esdata1" not found
Back-off restarting failed container"

But pvc "esdata1" created .Why this issue is coming ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you deploying the file?  Is that the _whole_ `docker-compose.yml` file (are there top-level `volumes:` and `networks:` blocks)?

Comment: Can you also share kubernetes files? I dont think you need to create volumes under docker files. You should use them as they are available on system but mount them as part of your k8s deployment.

Comment: on kompose up,every thing gets deployed in K8S

Comment: If you are using some sort of wrapper in deployment then try to fetch final yaml that got deployed in cluster via, 'kubectl get pod <my_pod> -o yaml --export ' it should give you the hint if everything is working as expected.

Comment: Can you share logs from k8s `elasticsearch` Pod?